# Manual steps involved when installing grails drools plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, drools

I was wondering if anybody else had experienced problems when installing the drools plugin for grails, becuase I had to do several manual steps to get this working and I thought that it would just install and work straight away.

To get this working I had to do the following steps:

Step 1 - Install drools plugin

```
grails install-plugin drools
```

Step 2 - Try running app

```
grails run-app
```

(A SAXParser exception prevented my app from starting up)

Step 3 - Remove Jar file to fix SAXParser Exception

```
.grails\1.2.2\projects\<your-project>\plugins\drools-0.3\lib
```

remove file - `xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar`

Step 4 - copy jar files from .grails folder to your own app folder

copy from

```
.grails\1.2.2\projects\<your-project>\plugins\drools-0.3\lib
```

to wherever the lib folder in your workspace is

Step 5 add jars to build path in Spring STS

Step 6 copy drools classes from .grails folder to appropriate folder in your own app

```
.grails\1.2.2\projects\<your-project>\plugins\drools-0.3\grails-app\domain\DroolsRule.groovy

.grails\1.2.2\projects\<your-project>\plugins\drools-0.3\grails-app\services\DroolsService.groovy
```

(remember and change the package in these 2 files to match your own applications package structure)

I am interested to see if other people have had similar problems because it took a while to figure out how to do this. Surely there should be an easier way of getting it to work than this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with grails 1.1.1 and drools-0.3 and it worked as mentioned at http://www.grails.org/Drools+Plugin 
Your issue must be probably specific to grails version.